# openiddict server with own user validation

Tags: openiddict

I new in openiddict and I see that openiddict uses its own database schema to store users and roles.
I would like to avoid that and use my own schema in any database.. and implement my own sql query to validate if the user exists or not (with the provided password) during the authentication.
I am doing it in c#.
How can i do it?
Thanks a lot in advance for your answer!

I have tried the next:

- Creating a CustomeUserProvider
- Creating MyUserRepository
- Implementing FindByIdAsybc and FindByNameAsync where i would like to execute my own sql queries.